testdisk "unset' all the partitions on my device
I dual boot Windows and Ubuntu, and I was trying to recover data from my Ubuntu Partition, which was lost. So, I followed a tutorial on the internet and used testdisk for the task. I selected only the Ubuntu Partition, made a deep search and clicked "Write".
Then, I rebooted my device and tried to boot on Windows, but it only displayed the Blue Screen message saying that some components were missing. I then booted in Ubuntu with my Live USB and checked GParted:
Partitions displayed on GParted
Then I went to check on testdisk to see what happened, but:
Partitions displayed on testdisk
The partitions and their respective data (in this case, the Windows partition data) is still there, however, they're not being read by the system.
How can I fix that? I'd just like to "set" them again.

Do you have a backup of partition table or nay documentation on partition sizes by sector? With Windows the issue often is that it has to have the Windows System Reserved partition before the first NTFS. That is totally unformatted space with MSR flag. But then partition tools cannot see it, and may not restore it. At this point best to just totally reinstall & restore from backups. You do have backups? Required before any major changed.
